# converting a floating-point to decimal in the scientific form with fixed length

Tags: powershell

I want to convert a floating-point number (e.g., `123.45678`) to a decimal number in the scientific form with a fixed length (e.g., `1.234E02`). The code I have written so far is:

```powershell
do {
    try { [decimal]$some_float = Read-Host 'Please specify the float number' }
    catch { "Please only put positive numbers." }
    
} until ($some_float -is [decimal] -and $some_float -gt 0)

function convertFloat {
    param (
        [decimal]$inputFloat
    )

    $descimals = 3
    $order = [Math]::Floor([Math]::Log10($inputFloat))

    if (0 -gt $order) {
        $placeHolder = ""
    } else {
        $placeHolder = "0"        
    }
    
    return -join([Math]::Round($inputFloat / [Math]::Pow(10, ($order - $descimals))) / [Math]::Pow(10, $descimals), "E", $placeHolder, $order)
    
}

Write-Host (-join("the float is ", (convertFloat ($some_float * 1E3)), " in scintific form"))

"Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

However I get the below error:

```
Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "System.Object[]", for "op_Division" to type "System.Decimal": "Cannot
convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Decimal"."
At H:\foo\bar.ps1:23 char:12
+     return -join([Math]::Round($inputFloat / [Math]::Pow(10, ($order  ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

which I don't understand. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the canonical way to achieve what I'm looking for. Either by fixing my code or proposing a new one. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `return ([Math]::Round($inputFloat / [Math]::Pow(10, ($order - $descimals))) / [Math]::Pow(10, $descimals)), "E", $placeHolder, $order -join ""`

Comment: @notjustme yes. That's it. You are amazing. Care to elaborate in an answer? It would be great for me to learn and do not make the same mistake again.

Comment: I'll elaborate a bit later this evening when I get some free time but in short (very short), there was a mix of types and methods being used in the _wrong_ place. I also had a reason to move the `-join` to the end of the return line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the functions return line to the following will work.

```
return ([Math]::Round($inputFloat / [Math]::Pow(10, ($order - $descimals))) / [Math]::Pow(10, $descimals)), "E", $placeHolder, $order -join ""
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get a string representation in standard scientific notation, you can use [.NET format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-exponential-e-format-specifier):

```
PS C:\> [float]$someFloat = 123.45678
PS C:\> '{0:E3}' -f $someFloat
1.235E+002
```

If you need a custom exponential notation, take a look at [custom format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-e-and-e-custom-specifiers) which permits changes to the padding/style. Should you need to convert this back to a `[decimal]` of that precision:

```
PS C:\> ('{0:E3}' -f $someFloat) -as [decimal]
123.5
```